# Rationalising diastereoselectivity of hydroboration using stereoelectronics

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation, stereoselectivity, stereoelectronics

Using bulky reagents such as 9-BBN, hydroboration is often highly diastereoselective, giving rise to the 1,2-*anti* diastereomer:

[image]

This is easily explained using a steric argument, with the major product resulting from minimisation of allylic strain in the transition state. This is essentially the Houk model, though in the context of hydroboration is often described as the reactive-conformer model.

While a steric argument works in many cases, it isn't fool-proof – increasing the size of a group does not necessarily increase the selectivity as would broadly be expected by the above model.

To rationalise this, Houk has proposed a *stereoelectronic component* in the transition state – this is perfectly plausible as electronics evidently contribute to the conformational preference of the molecule. What Houk does not expand on is the exact nature of the stereoelectronic effects (this is not unusual, stereoelectronics are often invoked to rationalise unexpected experimental results without justification).

> What is the nature of the stereoelectronic component when determining diastereoselectivity of hydroboration and in what situations should it be invoked?

Comment: This is a great question. If we were all honest, then we would call steric interactions/effects as that what they are: electronic effects. If they had a (likely) mechanism candidate, then it were probably possible to investigate this from a quantum chemical point of view; and even then it would be a snapshot. I think generalisation on this topic is difficult. It is a quite interesting to investigate though, and I'm quite certain that we'll see more of this eventually.